# Windows 7 BSOD: Remove any newly installed hard drives or hard drive controllers

Tags: windows-7, boot, bsod, system-recovery

The motherboard in my old system died, so I moved the hard drive over to my backup system and now I'm receiving this error. I'm able to read the drive perfectly fine in the Recovery screen and it ask for my windows login password and that processes fine.

1. Tried chkdsk /f no errors found
2. Tried repairing bootrec and rebuild but I keep getting this error "**total identified windows installations: 0**"
3. Tried system restore in the system recovery option screen.
4. Safe mode receives the same blue screen error.
5. Ran SFC no file problems
6. Also tried manually rebuilding the boot.ini, crashed it but windows detected and auto rebuilt it from the backup. But still same blue screen.

> A problem has been detected and windows has been shut down to prevent
>   damage to your computer.
>
> If this is the first time you've seen this stop error screen, restart
>   you computer. If this screen appears again, follow these steps:
>
> Check for viruses on your computer. Remove any newly installed hard
>   drives or hard drive controllers. Check your hard drive to make sure
>   it is properly configured and terminated. Run CHKDSK /F to check for
>   hard drive corruption, and then restart your computer.
>
> Technical Information:
>
> - STOP: 0x0000007B (0xFFFFF880009A98E8,0xFFFFFFFFC000000D,0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000)

Comment: Change the hard drive emulation mode. If it's RAID, try AHCI. If it's AHCI, try RAID. If that doesn't work, try IDE/compatibility. If you're getting zero identifiers windows installations, you didn't load the driver when it asked you if you wanted to.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz this is in the Bios correct? cause currently I can't login to windows at all. It should be AHCI, i'll try RAID to see if it'll get me in

Comment: how alike are these 2 systems?  because if they use different MB and video and nics and all, the disk inaccesable is just the first of the problems. Getting your user data out and reinstalling might be nessisary/desired even after you do get it all limping along.

Comment: @Psycogeek Usually, the boot device is the only major issue. Windows itself does the rest once it loads. At worst, you may need to add a few drivers.

Comment: @Psycogeek motherboards are different I would say 70% the same. As long as I get back into windows I can easily fix any nic or vid driver problem. Microsoft suggest this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976 but I can't get into windows to do it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz no luck, my only options where IDE and RAID. It was currently on IDE. I tried raid and also played with some of the sub settings no luck. I need to edit the registry some how. Any other ideas, knowing what the problem (AHCI) is, helps out a lot. now just solving it is the task.

Comment: does anyone know what a BCD4Windows is?  Mobile techie says :after moving a disk to new h/w or changing a mobo then it is very simply solved by using Fix HDC or Fix IDE tools to inject a generic controller. These are both available on the UBCD4Windows or as standalone tools.  http://think-like-a-computer.com/2011/03/03/stop-0x0000007b-windows/  Same basic idea that David presented but to get the drivers back to "compatable" things too?

Comment: Wait Hold on... standby. i'm in the System Recovery screen, and at the command prompt I typed regedit just to see what would happen and it opened up the Registry Editor... i'm going to manually change the driver set according to what MS says here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976 i'll report back... if that doesn't work i'll try your method @Psycogeek

Comment: http://www.ubcd4win.com/

Comment: the manual change didn't working... @Psycogeek where can i get FIX_HDC standalone so i can run from command prompt via usb drive

Comment: @acctman "Fix HDC or Fix IDE tools to inject a generic controller. These are both available on the UBCD4Windows" link above your comment.

Comment: @Moab correct but they're not available as standalone though. was looking for just Fix HDC

Comment: i'm back in i ended up using http://www.911cd.net/forums//index.php?showtopic=24245 its a standalone Fix_7hdc.vbs took less then 5secs to run and done

Answer (score 2):

I download and used the Vbscript from here: http://www.911cd.net/forums//index.php?showtopic=24245 install the file to a usb drive and ran from the System Recovery command prompt screen.

used the command: cscript Fix_7hdc.vbs /enable /search

Answer (score 2):

If anyone has this BSOD code, this worked for me:

I have an Inspiron 1545 and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>, and then deleted the following line of text:

```
/NOEXECUTE=OPTIN /MININT
```

Then, it boots.